# How do I find out from powershell if I am on a server or workstation?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

[This doc explains how to get your windows version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724834(v=vs.85).aspx), but to find it in PowerShell is harder.

`[System.Environment]::OSVersion` has a lot of good info but not the Server-Workstation Flag...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$osInfo = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem
$osInfo.ProductType
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> ```
> ProductType
> Data type: uint32
> Access type: Read-only
> Additional system information.
> Work Station (1)
> Domain Controller (2)
> Server (3)
> ```

So if the value is `1`, then you are on a workstation OS.

If it's `2` you're on a domain controller.

If it's `3` you're on a server that is not a domain controller.

---

If you're on an old version of Windows / PowerShell and want something that will work across all of them, it's the same, but with `Get-WmiObject`:

```
$osInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
$osInfo.ProductType
```

Comment: `Get-CimInstance` must be a cmdlet not available on the Win7 version of powershell?

Comment: Ok, that's pretty cool. I don't mess with windows much, but do try and work with powershell a bit (a little bit) and do have both older and current powershell (but only the older Win7 virtualized on a network server where I can reach it via rdesktop from Linux). So I learned the `Get-CmiInstance -ClassName` and `Get-WmiObject -Class` distiction -- thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin WMI goes back a *long* time in Windows. An open source version called OMI is also available for other platforms like linux, but CIM is an open standard and so Microsoft recommends the CIM cmdlets going forward, but WMI is alive and well _within_ Windows and will continue to be. PowerShell, starting with the newly released version 6, is open source and cross platform and you can install it on Linux. You might be able to run the CIM cmdlets from *nix against Windows, even older versions. It would be interesting to try.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The CIM cmdlets were [introduced in PowerShell v3](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2016/02/10/using-the-powershell-cim-cmdlets-for-fun-and-profit/), which is also [available for Windows 7](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/06/02/weekend-scripter-install-powershell-3-0-on-windows-7/). The CIM cmdlets do network communication via WinRM, which has a number of advantages over COM/RPC (which the WMI cmdlets are using).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Hah! -- worked like a champ! We are now both `Get-CmiObject` and `Get-WmiObject` capable. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

```
(Get-ComputerInfo).OsProductType
```

On my machines this returned either `WorkStation` or `Server`.

Comment: Note that `Get-ComputerInfo` isn't available prior to PowerShell v5.1.

Comment: While this is convenient, it comes with two caveats (beyond requiring PSv5.1+): (a) Execution takes on the order of seconds, and even asking only for the property of interest (`Get-ComputerInfo -Property OsProductType`) doesn't speed things up. (b) A progress bar is invariably shown during execution.

Comment: Thank you Kory! I don't feel like upgrading 1000 servers to ps5.1. this will be handy when all the machines are up to date.

Comment: Struggling with 1000 servers running Legacy powershell sounds worse than updating them to 5.1 LOL

Comment: @PsychoData, well, those 1000 are all in different domains in different locations, at different customer sites ;) if they were all on the same network you could just Chef them or something.

Comment: The only tricky version is PowerShell 3 and 4 - which are fairly rare, and could likely be handled 1-off. 
Otherwise you just need to install WMF 5.1 and you will be updated to PowerShell 5.1, which is sufficient. The Docs page for [WMF 5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/wmf/setup/install-configure?#download-and-install-the-wmf-51-package) includes scripts for testing and installing on most machines (including many of those edge-cases) in the ZIP downloads.

Answer (score -2):

(Get-WmiObject win32_OperatingSystem).Caption